cannot access message id beacuse the interaction.response.send_message() returns none with discord.py
@bot.tree.command(name='create_dungeon')
async def create_dungeon(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    new_doc_id = create_document(str(interaction.user))
    if new_doc_id == False:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Can't create more than one dungeon per user!")
    else:
        created_doc_query = maplestory_collection.find_one({"_id": new_doc_id})
        dps_players_count = len(created_doc_query["Dps"])
        tank_players_count = len(created_doc_query["Tank"])
        healer_players_count = len(created_doc_query["Healers"])
        class_types_max_players_and_counts = [
            ("Dps", dps_players_count, 10),
            ("Healer", healer_players_count, 3),
            ("Tank", tank_players_count, 4)
        ]

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Dungeon", description=f'Leader: {interaction.user} - ID {interaction.user.id}')
        for class_type, count, max_players in class_types_max_players_and_counts:
            embed.add_field(name=f"{class_type}", value=f"{max_players}/{count}")
        
        view = MyView(doc_id=new_doc_id, original_message_id=None, creator_id=interaction.user.id)
        view.create_buttons(buttons_info=buttons_info)
        
        message = await interaction.response.send_message(view=view, embed=embed)
        # message returns None even though it should return a Message object


Message var should return message object but returns none? im trying to get the id of the message  and then setting it for the view attribute original_message_id but its outputting an error TypeError

My guess is you need to create the message yourself with discord.Message(), rather than letting interaction.response.send_message() create it internally.

I have looked at the documentation of discord.py and have come to the conclusion that your problem is likely due to how interaction.response.send_message() does not return any value, so attempting to assign a variable to its output assigns None.
I found the above information at The documentation page for InteractionResponse.send_message(), as no return values are listed for the method.
It may be necessary for you to find another way to achieve your goal that doesn't require the ID of the response, as I cannot find a way to retrieve that ID other than sending it then getting the most recent post in the channel, which may cause problems due to potential messages being sent between the bot's response and getting the message.

thanks i just noticed that too ye, i found a way to retrieve it by using interaction.original_response() thank you though!!!

It seems I may have posted the only answer that was even relevant then. Could you please accept my answer as the solution, it might help anyone who may have the same problem too.

sure i did, i never knew it was possible since its my first post.

That's alright, it is my first answer too!
